# How can I execute a SQL query after 10 seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql, schedule

I would execute a SQL query like this :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name,surname)
VALUES ('john','john')
```

But just one time after 10 seconds for example.

Somethings like this :

```
CREATE 
ON SCHEDULE AFTER 10 seconds
INSERT INTO mytable (name,surname)
VALUES ('john','john')
```

I'm waiting for your answers

Comment: After each 10 Seconds or for only one time you need to schedule?

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Only one time i need, not "EVERY interval" so

Comment: @ioh rDBMS? SQL server, Oracle or mysql or any other?

Comment: Event Scheduler http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, for more information about creating events in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

```
CREATE EVENT DO_INSERT_OP
ON SCHEDULE
AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
DO INSERT INTO mytable (name,surname)
VALUES ('john','john');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be done though using [SLEEP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;

SELECT SLEEP(10);

INSERT INTO mytable (name,surname)
VALUES ('john','john');
```